# Finding proper references for a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In my visual studio 2012 project, I am using a nuget package. This package brings a lot of references with it.

Now, in my project, I need to use a method, I know this method exists, because it is one of the essential methods for this package. The problem is, that I don't know what to reference in my class file, in order to use this method. Is there any way of finding a method inside of a reference in order to properly add this reference to my class file? How do I approach this?

Comment: Look at the assemblies in the object browser to find the class you're looking for.

Comment: Can you maybe be a little more specific what method/package/whatever are you trying to use? Also, have you tried to use your good old friend Mr.Google?

Comment: @SLaks: That was it. Thanks. You can put a reply here so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the assemblies in the object browser to find the class you're looking for.